# How to tell if page is in Mobile View in C#

Tags: development, mobile

I have developed an application page within SharePoint 2010 and need to tweak the contents for the mobile view.

I can determine if the page is a mobile page by using the Query String however i am interested to know if there is somthing within the Object Model that does this parsing for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check following static method:

SPMobileUtility.IsMobilePageRequest